# Flat file export in Acumatica creates space lines in the file

Tags: export, acumatica, scenarios

I've created an export scenario using "ACH Provider" in ACUMATICA, the problem is when it creates the file, at the end of the data, it creates lines without data (space lines)... I would appreciate any suggestion to avoid this kind of issue.

[Flat file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmI4z.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue… ACH provider has BlockSize parameter where you can assign a value. I put 1 and the blank lines have deleted from the flat file...
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMtNh.jpg)